# Cambiar valor clave desde la consola en FireBase

Tags: android, firebase

He realizado mi primera base de datos en `FireBase`, pero he cometido un error ortográfico en una de las claves. El problema es que no puedo modificar el campo desde la consola.
¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Mi árbol es algo parecido a esto:

**tesnologias** <--- este es el valor que quiero cambiar a **tecnologia**
 ----c++ : 10
 --android: 25
 --java: 140
 --c#: 66

Comment: pues me da que la vas a tener que borrar y hacerla de nuevo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes exportar el json que en definitiva es un archivo de texto, editarlo y luego importarlo de nuevo. Las opciones de exportar e importar están arriba a la derecha cuando ves el json en la consola.

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a **cambiar el nombre del proyecto** desde la consola de Firebase, **esto no se puede realizar**, debes crear uno nuevo proyecto con el nombre correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys quería cambiar el valor de uno de los campos